# Update state or update classlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a ReactJS functional component that should update the class of an element within same component on a click event.

The question is really simple and I am probably overthinking it as performance-wise. Am I better of converting the functional component so that it manages state and I change class depending on the state? Or am I better of with changing class onClick with classList.add('active') ?

If anyone has any idea which would be better please let me know :)

Comment: If you want to change the behavior of your component without using inputs, you have a stateful component. You can't have a functional stateless component that on its own, changes its state. Make it a stateful component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to change elements classes in relation with some internal state of the component (that you change with onClick handler), then you should go with stateful components (class components or use Hooks).

I strongly suggest you to avoid directly accessing DOM elements and manually add classes. React has it's own way to keep control of these things.